# setAllowedContentTypes: how to use it on more than one filetype

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsopenpanel

In `NSOpenPanel` this is the easy part, enabling 1 filetype for opening:

```
NSArray uttypes;

uttypes=[UTType typesWithTag:@"ach" tagClass:UTTagClassFilenameExtension conformingToType:nil];

[openfilepanel setAllowedContentTypes:uttypes];
```

Now what do I do if I would like to enable more than one filetype for opening?
I only want to be able to open files that 'belong to' my application, no others.

working on MacOS 12.2

Michel

Comment: `uttypes` is an array, why use an array with only one object? Why not add other?

Comment: thanx! I knew uttypes was an array, but I didn't realise I had to use methods from the NSArray class to fill it. Now I got it!